# edge can not show github markdown list

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

As shown in the picture, with the same page on github, left side is edge and the right side is chrome. Why edge can not show the markdown list?
[image: edge and chrome]

I have tried to update the edge version. Maybe it's the influence of a plugin?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of style?

Comment: @SadraSabouri oh, could you please say more? how to change style in github?, thanks

Comment: I meant maybe Edge renders bullet points as an indented new line. I don't have an Edge browser and can not reproduce your bug, right now. I will update this thread once I get access to an Edge browser.

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you use any userstyles? Are you seeing anything in your dev console? If you inspect that element, do you see anything weird in the CSS? The monospaced fonts look weird in Edge, too... what OS are you on?

Comment: "Maybe it's the influence of a plugin?"—do you mean a browser extension? Why not disable them and find out? Or try an Incognito window, where most extensions are likely to be disabled?